# how to create document library in sharepoint on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript

when a user click html button document library should be created.I have seen some where they used app development method by modifying app.js file but I want to implement this through .txt file using sharepoint designer.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy the below code snipped below the PlaceHolderMain line i.e.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

          function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            alert('List created');
          }

          function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
              alert('request failed to create a list' );
          }

          function createNewList() {
              var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
              this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
              //Logic to create a new list and library
              clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
          }
           </script>    
           <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Create a new list/ Library" OnClick="createNewList()" />
```

Hope this help you.